# How to Create a variable to read a properties file many times

Tags: java, variables, selenium-webdriver, properties

**Observation:**
I would like to create a variable that can be used in tests that will allow me to only type the variable name instead calling the file then method.

Example ( would like to something like this )

```
propReader reader = new propReader();
```

which would replace this:

```
By username = By.xpath(propReader.setup("username")
```

and would look like this:

```
By username = By.xpath(reader("usrname");
```

Basically, I would like to simplify the call.

---

I tried to create this variable, but with no luck `propReader.setup(); setup = new propReader.setup();`

I'm not experienced enough to create the variable yet - just do not know what to look for.

My Properties File:

```
static Properties prop = new Properties();
    
    public static String setup(String key) throws Exception {
        String propPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\melos\\configs\\setup.properties";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(propPath);
        prop.load(fis);
    
        String value = prop.get(key).toString();
    
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            throw new Exception("Value is not specified for key: " + key + "in properties file");
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

My pageobjects file:

```
public class userLoginObj extends baseClass {

By username = By.xpath(propReader.Setup("username"));
By password = By.xpath(propReader.Setup("password"));
By loginBtn = By.cssSelector(propReader.melosSetup("loginBtn"));
public userLoginObj() throws Exception {

}
```

My properties file: (snippit)

```
username = //div\[@id='q-app'\]/div/div/main/div/div\[2\]/div/label/div/div/div/input
password = //div\[@id='q-app'\]/div/div/main/div/div\[2\]/div/label\[2\]/div/div/div/input                                             
loginBtn = .q-btn--standard .block
```

Comment: Yeah... don't do this. Create a proper [page object](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/encouraged/page_object_models/) and put the locators in the class itself. It will make your life much, much easier... reading, debugging, etc.